# Impact from EOL of IE11 for VB6 using MSHTML

Tags: vb6, internet-explorer-11, webbrowser-control

We have VB6 LOB app that makes extensive use of the MSHMTL.* and IEFRAME.*  To be clear, nothing is running in IE11 and there's zero ActiveX.  We use these for displaying reports and the like.

With the end of IE11 being announced here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge) and elsewhere, there's some confusion as to whether the DLLs, etc. will likewise go away.

**Anyone know more since TechNet has pretty bare bones info on this?**

In advance, save any comments to port to .NET or why still VB6.  It's tens of thousands of lines of code, works perfectly, and is not on the internet - so not a security risk nor will .NET have added any value.  Helps, too, that it's portable as all the dependencies exist even now on latest Windows 10 releases.

Comment: Seems like a good question if your dependencies will continue to exist in future versions of Windows. If not however I think you would be able to install them yourselves, one way or another.

Comment: End Of Life means that MS is terminating support of IE, not that IE is 'going away' (at least anytime soon).  Future versions of Windows may not include IE, but as the article describes you can install IE separately.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs

That's the key, doesn't matter if IE11 is pre-installed or accessible to a user without manual intervention, but there is nothing about the mshtml.dll, iefreame.dlll  that can be used to render HTML and more inside an app.

Comment: mshtml.dll and ieframe.dll (aka shdocvw.dll) _are_ IE.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741313(v=vs.85).  (Although that MS doc states 'IE 4', it's still applicable to current IE, afaik).  If IE is installed, mshtml.dll and ieframe.dll will be there.

Comment: @MarkL Yes, do know this about the dll's thanks.  The key part "If IE is installed."  It won't be and whilst for us in-house it's a matter of installing it, for other parties using it there will be push-back on installing IE 11.  Even if they never launch it or see it,  it's toxic waste, deservedly.  But using it as a rendering engine for HTML where it doesn't touch the internet is not a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Lets read the page you linked to

> Beginning January 12, 2016, only the most current version of Internet
> Explorer available for a supported operating system receives technical
> support and security updates.

and from the table

> Windows 10      Internet Explorer 11

That page does not announce the end of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yes, I can read.  But there's a lot more to it than that inasmuch as there are many programs that use web rendering etc. features that are IE dependent.  The alternative is re-write to Chromium or Webkit.  This is NOT trivial and impossible for VB6 apps, plus not internet-facing.  And if IE were such a massive risk now, it would get pulled.  I get it, stuff needs to die. But dragging a lot of folks down as you die is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The page says what is well known. It is 4 years old after all.

What is says is that only the last version of Internet Explorer for a OS version will receive updates.

If you bought Windows 8 with Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11 is available for that version, you will only receive updates for Internet Explorer 11.

So if your version of Windows supports Internet Explorer 11 you must update to it IE 11 to continue receiving security updates.

If your OS version only supports IE 10 you will receive updates for IE 10.

And there is nothing about programming in this, it is about IE support policy.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing from Microsoft that indicated other than IE11 will not be installed on future releases of Windows 10. They do say that IE will be supported for as long as whatever they decide it will be if IE 11 is on a given PC.  That's not the same thing.

Further and most important for what I care about is, what about MSHMTL.* and IEFRAME.*

Will they be there whether or not IE11 is installed? And yes, I know this is basically IS (over-simplification by some that responded), but that's not at all the same thing.

Windows has included many legacy dependencies for ages.

So unless anyone has something better to say that read what they wrote or the line, that would be welcome and feel free to comment and re-open this, but so far there's nothing to actually answer that concern, albeit perhaps I did not ask it as specifically as this.